# Javascript replace query string + with a space

Tags: javascript, url, query-string, decode

I'm grabbing the query string parameters and trying to do this:

```
var hello = unescape(helloQueryString);
```

and it returns:

```
this+is+the+string
```

instead of:

```
this is the string
```

Works great if %20's were in there, but it's +'s. Any way to decode these properly so they + signs move to be spaces?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

The [`decodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Functions/decodeURIComponent) function will handle correctly the decoding:

```
decodeURIComponent("this%20is%20the%20string"); // "this is the string"
```

Give a look to the following article:

- [Comparing `escape()`, `encodeURI()`, and `encodeURIComponent()`](http://xkr.us/articles/javascript/encode-compare/)

Comment: the question is specifically asking about strings with + instead of %20

Answer (score 0):

Adding this line after would work:

```
hello = hello.replace( '+', ' ' );
```

Comment: hello = hello.replace(/\+/g, ' ') if you anticipate more spaces between words.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to do (this way you don't get giant gaps of spaces): hello.replace(/\++/, '')